# How can I make a sound trail off at the end in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using winsound in Python to play a short Om chanting sound at the end of my program (in order to emphasize how cool the plot generated by the program is). The Om sound I'm playing is stored in a .wav file. I'd like to make the sound trail off near the end of the clip, so that the volume smoothly reduces to zero and the clip does not end abruptly. How can I make that happen?

Here's the code I'm using to play a sound:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('om1.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to edit the wav file. Add a fade out with audacity (open source), then just use your existing code to play it

Answer (score 1):

winsound does't seem to provide fade-out. You may edit the .wav file using e.g. Audacity.